# In VS themes what is the name of the marker(+) in the editor window for the collapsible region?

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a VS theme project for VS 2022 and I am trying to identify the item circled in red below. I am using Visual Studio Color Theme Designer 2022.

[image]

Does anyone know the name of this item?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idex.colorthemedesigner2022) or just within Visual Studio itself?  I know what its called in Visual Studio standalone.

Comment: Yes I am using the Visual Studio Color Theme Designer...  trying to find this item "[+]"  has  not gotten me anywhere...

Comment: Are you ok with using whats built in to Visual Studio to change the color of these controls? If so, I can post an answer.

Comment: @TimothyG. Sure, by all means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to change the colors of this, you can do so by going to Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors and changing "Outlining Margin Square" and "Outlining Margin Vertical Rule":

[image: fonts and colors options to change outlining margin]